# Filter data current this month SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Please help, I am trying to show my data by just this month.

This is my query now :

```
select 
    IdEnt,
    convert(varchar(20),InputDate,103) as 'InputDate',
    userID,
    Nominal,
    TypeCost,
    convert(varchar(20),EntDate,103) as 'EntDate',
    EntParty,
    Premi,
    Div,
    RemarksAgent,
    RemarksFinance 
from 
    entReq 
where
    userID = $_SESSION[userID] 
order by 
    InputDate desc;
```

Comment: You want to filter data based on `InputDate` or `EntDate` ?

Comment: i want by inputdate

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using ?

Comment: sql server 2016

Comment: Add this `WHERE MONTH(InputDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())`

Comment: @iSR5 it works tooo...thank uuuuuuu

Comment: @iSR5, without year that will not be correct

Comment: @uzi true, he should be able to add the year same way.

Comment: @iSR5 - Also that will make query non sargable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using [`EOMONTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql)

```
SELECT ident, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), inputdate, 103) AS 'InputDate', 
       userid, 
       nominal, 
       typecost, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), entdate, 103)   AS 'EntDate', 
       entparty, 
       premi, 
       div, 
       remarksagent, 
       remarksfinance 
FROM   entreq 
WHERE  userid = $_SESSION[userID]  
       AND inputdate >= Dateadd(dd, 1, EOMONTH(Getdate(), -1)) 
       AND inputdate < Dateadd(dd, 1, EOMONTH(Getdate())) 
ORDER  BY inputdate DESC;
```

For older versions :

First Day of Month : `DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)`

Last Day of Month : `DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))`

Comment: weawww, it works...so many thanks...

i've got one question, sorry..hehe
how if i'm want to filter by date?

Comment: `inputdate = whateverdate`